# SELECT Date with max date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, dblink

I have expression with db_link to MS SQL:

```
   select b."Str" as "State" ,a."_Fld9059" as "Date" from 
   "_InfoRg9050"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM a INNER JOIN 
   "EnumTexts"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM b
   on a."_Fld9052RRef" = b."_IDRRef"
   where a."_Fld10998" = '1104000009' and
   a."_Fld10998" = to_date(max(a."_Fld9059"),'dd.mm.yyyy')
   order by a."_Fld9059" desc;
```

I want to upload value with maximum date. Can anybody help me ?
When I run this query I get ORA-00934 error.

Comment: What is the significance of the string `'1104000009'` ?  And how could a value in the `_Fld10998` column equal this string and also equal a date?

Comment: Please update with sample data and your expected output.

Comment: I rewrote my query as 
`select b."Str" as "State" from 
( select b."Str" as "State" ,a."_Fld9059" as "Date" from "_InfoRg9050"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM a INNER JOIN "EnumTexts"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM b
 on a."_Fld9052RRef" = b."_IDRRef"
 where a."_Fld10998" = '1104000009' 
 order by a."_Fld9059" desc)
where a."_Fld9059" = MAX(a."_Fld9059");` but got the same error

Comment: "_Fld10998" has VARCHAR values and "_Fld9059" has DATE values in MS SQL base

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate cause of the error you are getting is that `MAX()` appears in the `WHERE` clause.  One possible workaround, which might be what you intended, would be to use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to identify the maximum date:

```
SELECT b.Str AS State,
       a._Fld9059 AS Date
FROM _InfoRg9050 a
INNER JOIN EnumTexts b
    ON a._Fld9052RRef = b._IDRRef
WHERE a._Fld10998 = '1104000009' AND
      a._Fld10998 = (SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(_Fld9059, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) FROM _InfoRg9050)
ORDER BY a._Fld9059 DESC
```

However, it is not clear why you are comparing `_InfoRg9050._Fld10998` to both the string `'1104000009'` *and* a date.  You will need to resolve this on your own I believe to get a meaningful result.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. You helped me a lot, but the query returns ORA-02070:The remote database does not support the named capability in
           the context in which it is used.

Comment: You have some issue going on with your schema.  I'm afraid I can only help by giving you what I believe to be a correct query.  The rest is up to you.

Comment: MS SQL doesn't have TO_DATE() function. What use MS SQL ?

Comment: Use this: `CONVERT(datetime, '18.01.2017', 104);`

Comment: `a."_Fld9059" = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT("_Fld9059", 'dd.mm.yyyy', 104)) FROM "_InfoRg9050"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM)` returns ORA-01482: unsupported character set.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I got it.

```
SELECT b."Str" AS "State"
FROM "_InfoRg9050"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM a
INNER JOIN "EnumTexts"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM b
ON a."_Fld9052RRef" = b."_IDRRef"
WHERE a."_Fld10998" = '1104000009' AND
a."_Fld9059" = (select MAX(a."_Fld9059") from "_InfoRg9050"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM a
INNER JOIN "EnumTexts"@SQLSERVER.UISLAB.COM b
on a."_Fld9052RRef" = b."_IDRRef"     
where a."_Fld10998" = '1104000009')
ORDER BY a."_Fld9059" DESC
```